# Sidebar position occupying after logging out

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, bootstrap-4

I'm working on a project in VUEJS where you login and see a dashboard with a sidebar. When I logout from the sidebar, the login page div moves to the right and is in the correct position only when I refresh. This is the styling for the Login div

```
.vertical-center {
  text-align: left;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 4%
}

.inner-block {
  width: 450px;
  height: 450px;
  margin: auto;
  background: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0px 14px 80px rgba(68, 223, 12, 0.2);
  padding: 40px 55px 45px 55px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
```

I know the spacing is from the sidebar. The issue persists even when I give the scoped attribute to the styling.

Comment: `This is the code for the Login div`, there is no code. Maybe you forgot to add.

Comment: I've corrected the statement. Thanks

Comment: I meant to provide the HTML code.

Comment: We can't really help without the html and a screenshot of the rendered page at least.